# Oracle select to find occurences of couple of status

Tags: sql, oracle, select, gaps-and-islands

I have the following data:

```
STATUS                      DATE                        TIME                        
B                           20181011                    13:28:27                    
B                           20181011                    13:36:05                    
B                           20181011                    15:28:40                    
I                           20181011                    15:28:57                    
I                           20181011                    15:41:56                    
I                           20181018                    08:21:43                    
B                           20181018                    13:38:00                    
I                           20181019                    17:03:00                    
B                           20181023                    09:45:54                    
I                           20181023                    10:35:44                    
I                           20181023                    10:38:11
```

Every time I have a sequence of STATUS 'B', I must use the last, the same for STATUS 'I' so I can get every couple of this status considering the rule above and calculate the time between them. I tried some selects without success also I couldn't find any questions like mine.

edit:
I would like the select could make the result below:

```
STATUS                      DATE                        TIME                        
B                           20181011                    15:28:40                    
I                           20181018                    08:21:43                    
B                           20181018                    13:38:00                    
I                           20181019                    17:03:00                    
B                           20181023                    09:45:54                    
I                           20181023                    10:38:11
```

Comment: I guess it would help if you posted desired result, based on that sample data.

Comment: I edited the question with the expected result.

Comment: This is a typical "Gaps and Island" problem. Search around StackOverflow. The solution has been documented many times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option, which - through CTEs - leads the way so that you could trace what's going on. I suggest you execute them one by one.

Also, I *hope* that there's actually one `DATE` datatype column; otherwise, if there are two of them (date and time), you're storing them into `VARCHAR2` columns (probably) which is a bad idea - I'd suggest you to change the model and use one `DATE` datatype column.

Here we go:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (status, datum) as
  2    (select 'B', to_date('11.10.2018 13:28:27', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  3     select 'B', to_date('11.10.2018 13:36:05', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  4     select 'B', to_date('11.10.2018 15:28:40', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  5     select 'I', to_date('11.10.2018 15:28:57', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  6     select 'I', to_date('11.10.2018 15:41:56', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  7     select 'I', to_date('18.10.2018 08:21:43', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  8     select 'B', to_date('18.10.2018 13:38:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  9     select 'I', to_date('19.10.2018 17:03:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 10     select 'B', to_date('23.10.2018 09:45:54', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 11     select 'I', to_date('23.10.2018 10:35:44', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 12     select 'I', to_date('23.10.2018 10:38:11', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
 13    ),
 14  inter as
 15    (select status, lag(status) over (order by datum) lag_status, datum
 16     from test
 17    ),
 18  inter_2 as
 19    (select status, datum,
 20       sum(case when status = nvl(lag_status, status) then 0 else 1 end) over (order by datum) grp
 21    from inter
 22    )
 23  select status, max(datum) datum
 24  from inter_2
 25  group by status, grp
 26  order by datum;

S DATUM
- -------------------
B 11.10.2018 15:28:40
I 18.10.2018 08:21:43
B 18.10.2018 13:38:00
I 19.10.2018 17:03:00
B 23.10.2018 09:45:54
I 23.10.2018 10:38:11

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

- `INTER` CTE selects `STATUS` value from the previous row
- `INTER_2` creates groups, based on whether previous and current row's `STATUS` column values are same or different
- the final query groups data by `STATUS` and `GRP` (group) and selects the `MAX` `DATUM` value

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tested all the solutions and your solution was best to fit my need.

Answer (score 0):

Get first all date time pairs that match the condition and join to the main table:

```
select tablename.* from (
  select mydate, mytime from tablename t
  where not exists (
    select 1 from tablename 
    where 
      tablename.status = t.status 
      and 
      concat(tablename.mydate, tablename.mytime) = (
        select min(concat(tablename.mydate, tablename.mytime)) from tablename where concat(mydate, mytime) > concat(t.mydate, t.mytime)
      )
  )
) d
inner join tablename
on d.mydate = tablename.mydate and d.mytime = tablename.mytime;
```

See [demo](http://tpcg.io/7leBPj)

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the gaps-and-islands problem.  For this version, I think `lead()` is the best approach:

```
select status, date, time
from (select t.*,
             lead(status) over (order by date, time) as next_status
      from t
     ) t
where next_status is null or next_status <> status;
```